# What are cross-platform free/Open source Framework to create Touch based web apps/site using HTML/CSS/JS available?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, mobile-website, multi-touch

What are **cross-platform** and **cross browser** and **license free/Open source framework** to create **Touch/Multitouch based** *Web apps/site* using HTML/CSS/JS, for mobile devices, specially for latest versions of Android, Blackberry, Windows 7, iphone and ipad available? For desktop websites I'm a jQuery lover.

I know [Sencha but it's not free](http://www.sencha.com/store/touch/license.php) I think.

I know jQtouch but it's only for iPhone and I also know jquery mobile but I'm not cofirm, is it as powerful as Sencha? It's not necessarily for me to go with **jquery mobile**, if there are another better framework available than this

I want to make compatible with Android, Blackberry, Windows 7 also. not only for iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery lover? Use Jquery Mobile http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Is jquery mobile capable to do all things which is possible with Sencha?

Comment: I am not familiar with Sencha, however the Jquery Mobile website is very clearly and well documented, so it should be relatively easy to compare. Jquery is very easy to extend also, especially if you are (as you say) already experienced in using it.

Comment: jQuery mobile is best for websites, Sencha is for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqtouch.com/ and http://jquerymobile.com/ are the ones that spring to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Over a million mobile developers use [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com). It leverages HTML5 and CSS3 and allows you to build amazing mobile applications without worrying a bunch of things you would otherwise do. It has layouts and a pile of widgets. The productivity is pretty high.

Update: Sencha is dual-licensed meaning that if you develop commercial software, you need to pay their fee. If you develop an open source application, Sencha is completely free!

See their licensing: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license.php

Comment: But I think sencha is only compatible with iOS and Android. No compatibility with blackberry and Windows phone 7.

Comment: "Apple iOS, Google Android, and other WebKit browsers comprise over 93% of US mobile web traffic." from their website.

Comment: OK So windows 7 phone and some older version of blackberry are not supported.

Comment: Over a million mobile developers? Or over a million people use Sencha-enabled sites?